# PHP snmp2_set error messages (return values)

Tags: php, snmp

In my PHP code i allways prefer the 'native' PHP snmp functions like `snmp2_set()`.

But unfortunately the above function does not provide sufficient feedback.

From the manual:

```
Return Values:

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
```

In case of unsuccessful execution in my apache2 error.log i see the detailed error/warning messages, like this:

```
PHP Warning:  snmp2_set(): Error in packet at 'enterprises.9.9.116.1.4.1.1.2.8048': wrongValue (The set value is illegal or unsupported in some way) in /var/www/modules/myfunc.php on line 2238 ...
```

Perhaps it is possible that a similar message is returned from the snmp2_set() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is no way to get this message from that function directly because this is how it works in PHP. A lot of methods will only return `true`/`false` and then raise a warning with an exact message.

You can still get access to this message by calling `error_get_last()`. It will return you an array with details about the error (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php).

Having said that, I would recommend to handle all warnings/notices as exceptions by registering own error handler that will convert such warnings/notices to exception which you can later catch in your code:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno , $errstr){
    throw new MyException($errstr, $errno);
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

and then:

```
try {
    snmp2_set(/* ... */);
} catch (MyException $e) {
    $e->getMessage(); // Here you will have your error message
}
```